# I have statistical data on my SQL queries, what can I do with that to make my app faster?

Tags: sql, performance, analysis

I have a J2EE application built on EclipseLink and running under Glassfish on Postgres. We're doing some performance analysis now.

I turned on pg logging on our build server and analyzed the output with pgfouine. Now that I have these charts and data from pgfouine, how should I interpret that to actually improve performance?

I think I want to find the most frequently used, but slower queries to get the most benefit. Reducing the number of frequently run queries (perhaps through caching) also seems like a sound approach.

Comment: Found a few queries which ran frequently but were replaced with some in-memory operations. Cut the runtime of our integration tests in half.

Answer (score 0):

Properly done indexing helps a lot. If a column appears in many WHERE clauses, consider marking it for indexing.

Comment: This depends also on the size of the table and data.  Sometimes a table scan on a huge table is much faster than going through an index first, then scanning through the table to find the location.

Comment: Some of my slower queries are INSERTS on tables with several indexes. There are downsides to indexing!